# iPhone Quartz - Call Drawing Method From Other Class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm trying to call a drawing method from `Class A` for example, the method located in `Class B`, the method is being called but no drawing happen.

```
- (void)drawIt
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:@"TEXT"];
    [string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(12, 51) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:35.0f]];
}
```

Why can I call this method from other class?

Answer (score 1):

First create class '`YourView`' which is subclass of UIView. Write allocation code `viewDidLoad` method which is in Class B

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
 YourView *temp = [[YourView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:temp];
}
```

Implement `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method in YourView.m

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithString:@"TEXT"];
    [string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(12, 51) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:35.0f]];
}
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to make this draw straight after init...
I also want to be able to draw and erase drawing manually

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UIView or some subclass you need to overload the drawRect method. So, inside drawRect you call your method in other class. Also, you can pass your context via parameter too.

Comment: Thank you, the calls is superclass is UITableView and I'm using to drawRect but I don't want to make the draw on the object init.